# How to change port in memsql from 9000 to something else

Tags: singlestore

I  am trying   to install the   dev  version of memsql in  centos7.

If I run # `sudo ./install.sh --simple-cluster --host=127.0.0.1`

I get the   error:

```
Port 9000 is already bound
```

Where   and how do I configure the  port   to a different one for this?

Answer (score 0):

```
./install.sh --simple-cluster --host=127.0.0.1 --port 9002
```